# Facebook friends list is empty, just for one specific user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-friends

Simply executing this query aiming to list all my friend's friends:

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/hisFacebookUserId/friends?return_ssl_resources=1&access_token=hisAccessToken
```

I obtain an empty `data` entry. => as if it had 0 friends. (but he has 800).

However, it works for many other users.

What might be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since v2.0 of the Facebook API, you can only get the friends who authorized your App too. It´s a (privacy) feature, not a bug.

> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Also, it´s not necessary to use an ID for the call, because you can only get the friends of the authorized User anyway:

```
/me/friends
```

**Btw, don´t forget to authorize Users with the `user_friends` permission.**

Comment: Even if i don't specify the 2.0 in the URL? It can't use the 1.0 any more?

Comment: you can´t use 1.0 in an App created after April 2014 - or in an App that was inactive before that.

Comment: Ok, however I'm the owner of the app, (so authorized) and he's my friend. Why can't I see his friends whereas I can see any other user's friends.

Comment: Yes sorry, I misspoked. For example: A is logged on the app through his Facebook. It retrieves his friends. B should be among the result but B isn't present..

Comment: please read my answer, that´s explained in there. you can ONLY get the friends of the authorized user and you can ONLY get those who authorized your app too. that´s how it is.

Comment: meaning: user B will only show up in the friendlist of user A if he authorized the app too

Comment: Exactly, that's why it's strange since both me and him, have authorized the application

Comment: in that case, you probably forgot to ask for the user_friends permission

Comment: Is it possible that this specific user (1 among 800) has restricted his access on his Facebook settings?

Comment: no, if he disabled the platform, he would not be able to use the app at all

Comment: I will check his permissions. It would make sense if ALL users were in the same case, but very weird, just him.

Comment: why? all those other users did not authorize your app, so of course they don´t show up in the list.

Comment: The context is: I've got an app where any users could authenticate through Facebook. For each user connected, I grab their friends that authorized the app. There are 800 users. For those 800 users, all respective friends list is well received. However for this 801th user...nothing.

Comment: ok, then it may indeed be a v1.0 app, and maybe it IS about a user setting. afaik you can hide friends on facebook.com, so even your friends don´t see...your friends...if you know what i mean.

Comment: Yes, I just debug his accessToken, it well has the `user_friends` scope... I investigate :)

Comment: Oh, I observe that it doesn't has the permission: `read_friendslist`, comparing to other users permissions.

Comment: Actually, no, there are other users that doesn't have it. So not essential.

Comment: that permission is irrelevant, it´s for friendlists, not friends